# JPA/Hibernate Auto generated timestamp field is not loaded

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In my entity I have two fields -

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private Date created;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private Date updated;
```

When new entity is created these two fields are populated (I have checked DB). But unfortunately these fields are not loaded on entity(i mean the object) after then entity is persisted, neither these fields are loaded if I fetch the entity.

I am using `spring-boot and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa of version 1.5.3-RELEASE`, with `MySQL`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm you are loading the entity in a new Session or that you enforce in a different way that the entity actually gets loaded from the database?

Comment: @JensSchauder: I am not sure what you mean by new Session, but I have tried to load the entity in a new transaction. And it didn't work.

The only different way I know is loading them manually from database, which will invalidate the use of JPA.

Answer (score 0):

For Creation and Updation Timestamp you may use the following code,

**Creation**

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "CREATED", updatable = false)
private Date Created;
```

**Updation**

```
@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "UPDATED")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date Updated;
```

Comment: None of `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` is not part of JPA and very specific to Hibernate implementation. 

I am looking for something JPA specific.